# How to execute function when action is fired or completes?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

### THE SHORT QUESTION

What is best practice for executing a function after an action has been triggered?

I'm tempted to detect the action in middleware. If its the action I want, execute the function and then pass the action to the reducers. But this seems a bit hacky?

FYI The function uses jQuery to get all codemirror elements on the page and clears the history of all of them

### THE FULL QUESTION WITH BACKGROUND (for those who want more depth)

The code I am working with (not my code) fires an action (FAKE_ACTION)

The payload of FAKE_ACTION is another action (REAL_ACTION).

FAKE_ACTION stores REAL_ACTION in a list in global redux state.

Later on, REAL_ACTION will be pulled from the list and triggered.

After REAL_ACTION is triggered I want to execute a function. Where should this function live?

Comment: This seems highly irregular.  Typically, apps use a tool like `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga` to achieve similar results.

Comment: i agree highly irregular sums it up nicely, but this is not my code - this is some deeply woven in logic that I have to put up with

Comment: It sounds like somebody is trying to build a queue of actions to be fired later.  `redux-saga` is probably the tool that would be used for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are wondering how to handle async operations (side effects) in a redux context. This happens indeed via a middleware but you don't have to write your own. There are projects like `redux-thunk` or better `redux-saga`. It is basically logic that stands between the `dispatch` and the reducers.

Comment: is it bad practice to execute a function in middleware? the function will clear the history of all codemirror elements on the page and has nothing to do with react or redux

Comment: I think it is fine to do whatever you want in the middleware. In most of the places the middleware is a place for handling side effects so that's its main purpose to do everything else that Redux can't (and it shouldn't).

Comment: didn't use this but felt it the most appropriate answer (ignoring my own answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function. In your actions, post an Ajax call when you dispatch a response you will be calling either a success callback or an error callback. So in dispatch, you can define your function.

```
export function loginUser(email, password) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(loginRequest())
    return ajax.post(URL_PREFIX+"/auth/login", { email, password })
      .then(res => {          
              // console.log("path: ", path)
          dispatch(loginSuccess(res))
         const value = loginUtils.getCurrentUser()  //function that you are talking about    
      })
      .catch(errors => {
        dispatch(loginFail(errors));
      })
  }
}
```

and in loginUtils the function getCurrentUser() is like below

```
export function getCurrentUser() {
return 'test'
}
```

Comment: Updated my post. Please check

Answer (score 1):

you have to perform asynchronus operation for this.
you can use either middleware like `redux-thunk` or either you can go for `javascript promise` or any other callback asynchronus function.

Answer (score 0):

Some useful answers here but none are quite what I'm after (given the messy codebase I'm working with) / didn't feel right.

I ended up using store.subscribe which allows you to subscribe to changes in the store's data and react accordingly.

See https://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe for more info